# How to get fresh db data with wc_get_order

Tags: woocommerce

I have a script that works as a daemon.
This script every so often is supposed to retrieve the order data and then processes the data.

In a situation where the script is running and retrieves the data of a given order and the order has a status of, for example, "on-hold" and then I change its status to "processing" the script still sees the status "on-hold" when I retrieve the data via wc_get_order because it uses an internal wp cache that is not refreshed.

So how do I retrieve the most current order data from the database.

I searched in the source code if there is perhaps a parameter to force the retrieval of data from the database but did not find it.

Comment: Before retrieve any data run wc_delete_shop_order_transients($order_id) to clear any cache ? Or run script after order is updated since will flush the cache anyway.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching I made it.

```
wp_using_ext_object_cache( false );
wp_cache_flush();
wp_cache_init();
```

Using this 3 lines of code clear cache.